# Excel - VBA, pulling row of data from several worksheet to Summary worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm VBA noobs, I want to make summary data from several worksheet altogether for my assignment, so here's what I get from several web..

```
Sub AddSummaryData()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim Newsh As Worksheet
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim ColNum As Integer
    Dim Num As Integer
    Dim RwNum As Long
    Dim Basebook As Workbook

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set Basebook = ThisWorkbook
    Set Newsh = Basebook.Worksheets("Summary")
    Newsh.Rows("14:27").ClearContents

   'The links to the first sheet will start in row 10
    RwNum = 10

  'Setting the Number
    Num = 0

   For Each Sh In Basebook.Worksheets
       If Sh.Name <> "Main" And Sh.Name <> "Input and Basis" And Sh.Name <> "Template" And Sh.Name <> "Summary" And Sh.Visible Then
            ColNum = 4
            RwNum = RwNum + 4
            Num = Num + 1
            'add number
            Newsh.Cells(RwNum, 1).Value = Num
            'Copy the sheet name in the A column
            Newsh.Cells(RwNum, 2).Value = Sh.Name

            For Each myCell In Sh.Range("A16,B16,F16")  '<--Change the range
            Newsh.Cells(RwNum, 4).Value = Sh.Range("E13")


                ColNum = ColNum + 2
                Newsh.Cells(RwNum, ColNum).Formula = _
                "='" & Sh.Name & "'!" & myCell.Address(False, False)
            Next myCell

            For Each myCell In Sh.Range("A17,B17,F17")  '<--Change the range

                Newsh.Cells(RwNum + 1, ColNum).Formula = _
                "='" & Sh.Name & "'!" & myCell.Address(False, False)
           Next myCell

           For Each myCell In Sh.Range("A18,B18,F18")  '<--Change the range

                Newsh.Cells(RwNum + 2, ColNum).Formula = _
                "='" & Sh.Name & "'!" & myCell.Address(False, False)
           Next myCell

           For Each myCell In Sh.Range("A19,B19,F19")  '<--Change the range

                Newsh.Cells(RwNum + 3, ColNum).Formula = _
                "='" & Sh.Name & "'!" & myCell.Address(False, False)

           Next myCell

        End If
    Next Sh

    'Opening Summary Sheet
    With Sheets("Summary")
        .Select
    End With

    Newsh.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
 End Sub
```

I don't understand why it's not working, as I'm not familiar with VBA, the data from  *ISO-1L,etc* worksheet, wont copy to the *summary* worksheet which in green highlight ..

**Image:**

[image: Sample image]

Comment: Which line it is giving the error? And second thing is are the ISO-1L and other sheets are visible or hidden?

Comment: The other sheets are visible, and second thing, yesterday i don`t even know which line giving it error...

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it`s solved already..

```
For Each Sh In Basebook.Worksheets
    If Sh.Name <> "Main" And Sh.Name <> "Input and Basis" And Sh.Name <> "Template" And Sh.Name <> "Summary" And Sh.Visible Then
        ColNum = 4
        RwNum = RwNum + 4
        Num = Num + 1
        'add number
         Newsh.Cells(RwNum, 1).Value = Num
        'Copy the sheet name in the column
        Newsh.Cells(RwNum, 2).Value = Sh.Name
        'Copy the Description in the column
        Newsh.Cells(RwNum, 4).Value = Sh.Range("E13")

        For Each myCell In Sh.Range("A16,B16,F16")  '<--Change the range


            ColNum = ColNum + 2
            Newsh.Cells(RwNum, ColNum).Value = myCell.Value
            Newsh.Cells(RwNum + 1, ColNum).Value = myCell.Offset(1, 0).Value
            Newsh.Cells(RwNum + 2, ColNum).Value = myCell.Offset(2, 0).Value
            Newsh.Cells(RwNum + 3, ColNum).Value = myCell.Offset(3, 0).Value
       Next myCell
```